# Silverlight 4 Hosting Requirement

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0, web-hosting

I would like to know if what are the technical specification both hardware and software (windows OS, IIS and the like) of a server to be able to host a silverlight 4 / .net 4 / wcf web service application.

Thank you

Comment: Silverlight is a client side technology so the server isn't really important here.

Comment: @Brian how about its web service?

Comment: That's a different question then isn't it.

Comment: (please don't abuse the flag-for-moderator-attention function)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need any server-side functionality, you can use any server you want because it will just post .xap file to user. On the other hand, in you are going to  implement RIA services for example, you gonna need .net 4.0 hosting platform.

Hope this helps, 
Ilya

Answer (score 1):

You can host a Silverlight in any Html file. All you need is to use the embed-tag.

There is nothing stopping you from hosting Silverlight on Apache running PHP if you want to, but naturally the default is to host it on IIS.

Look at this reply to a related question for an example: [embedding silverlight, anything like flash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816159/embedding-silverlight-anything-like-flash/816244#816244)

Edit:
I see that you changed your question, so this question may belong on another forum. Any computer able to run IIS will be able to host what you ask for. You will probably go for a server running Windows Server 2008, but the hardware specs depend on what your needs are. You should probably aim low first and add more power as you need it.

You may also be interested in using a cloud-based service like Microsofts Azure. It is perfect for hosting an application like yours and it is more or less infinitely scalable.

Comment: thanks for the alternative but what I'm actually looking for is the hardware and software specification in building a server which supports .net 4 application.

Answer (score 1):

Currently i´m working on a Silverlight 4 / WCF Ria Services project and i gathered some information about the software requirements for the server. The project is in the initial phase so the list below is not complete. About the hardware requirements i´m not sure. Here´s what i´ve got so far.

**OperatingSystem:**

- Windows 7
- Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Vista Service Pack 1
- Windows XP Service Pack 3

**IIS:**

- 6.0 or higher
- Enable ASP.NET for IIS using aspnet_regiis.exe

**Mime-Type (only IIS 6.0):**

- .xap application/x-silverlight-app
- .xaml    application/xaml+xml
- .xbap    application/x-ms-xbap

**.NET Framework:**

- 4.0 and ASP.NET;
- [WCF RIA Services V1.0 for Silverlight 4 and Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=cd3191a1-def4-4caa-8120-1f0bbcf4bb05&displaylang=en) 
  (Installation using Shell: msiexec /i RIAServices.msi SERVER=true)
- [ASP.NET MVC 2 RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c9ba1fe1-3ba8-439a-9e21-def90a8615a9&displaylang=en) 
  (this is optional, but we are using it, Installation using Shell: AspNetMVC2_VS2008.exe –x; msiexec /i aspnetmvc2.msi)

Comment: If it supports WinXP, it only requires IIS 5.1, as that's the version that's part of XP (32-bit). Since I've used WCF on XP, I know it works on IIS 5.1 (though I don't know about MVC).

Comment: @Gabe: I think you are right. IIS 5.1 should be fine. The Operating System requirements are based on the requirements of the .NET Framework 4.0